# how to add robot framework tests in go coverage

Tags: go, testing, automated-tests, robotframework, code-coverage

i am running some test cases in robot file and I am trying to generate the coverage data.
so for that i have generated a test_binary and using this command in Makefile

```
${GOROOT}/bin/go test -race -coverpkg="./..." -c -o test_binary -tags testrunmain .
```

then i have a coverage.sh file that is generating the coverage using this test_binary

```
/bin/test_binary -test.run "^TestRunMain$" -test.coverprofile=/coverage/coverage.out &
```

then there is a go test function
with function TestRunMain

```
func TestRunMain(t *testing.T) {
        go main()
        c := make(chan os.Signal)
        signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)
        <-c
}
```

currently only main function is getting included in coverage report and i want to cover all the test cases that are written in robot file (tests.robot)

Please give your valuable suggestions

Answer (score 0):

`go test` has nothing to do with getting coverage data of from your robot framework tests.

First, you compile the application/code that you want to get coverage out from with `-cover` flag to go build.

Second, you start the newly build app and ensure that GOCOVERDIR environment variable is set for it.

And then run robot framework scripts that interact with said binary.

Depending on the app itself, you might need to start the binary from RF itself but the steps are the same.

See; https://go.dev/testing/coverage/ for more details.